# Why .filter() in django returns duplicated objects?

Tags: django

I've followed django tutorial and arrived at [tutorial05](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/).

I tried to not show empty poll as tutorial says, so I added filter condition like this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
            choice__isnull=False
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

But this returned two objects which are exactly same.

I think *choice__isnull=False* caused the problem, but not sure.

Comment: You have two distinct objects in the database with identical values

Comment: check object id if its same then returning duplicate record else you know better.

Comment: @Sayse I looked up the table polls_question, but there is no duplicated poll.

Comment: `filter` is not capable of returning the same object twice. You must have either overridden the default manager which you're not showing us (which I doubt) or you have two distinct objects. Or its incorrect logic in the view

Comment: @Sayse That is not correct, `filter` is capable of returning the same object twice,  see [Django documentation for `distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`choice__isnull` causes the problem. It leads to join with `choice` table (to weed out `questions` without `choices`), that is something like this:

```
SELECT question.*
  FROM question
  JOIN choice
    ON question.id = choice.question_id
 WHERE question.pub_date < NOW()
```

You can inspect `query` attribute of `QuerySet` to be sure. So if you have one `question` with two `choices`, you will get that `question` two times. You need to use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) method in this case: `queryset.distinct()`.

Comment: By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d use distinct().

Answer (score 8):

Just use `.distinct()` at the end of your ORM.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but I figured it could help others looking up the same issue.
Instead of using `choice__isnull=False` with the `filter()` method, use it with `exclude()` instead to exclude out any questions without any choices. So your code would look something like this:

```
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).exclude(choice__isnull=True).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

By doing it this way, it will return only one instance of the `question`. Be sure to use `choice_isnull=True` though.

Answer (score -4):

Because you created two objects with same properties. If you want to ensure uniqueness, you should add validation in `clean` and add unique index on identifier field too.

Besides `filter` returns all the objects that match the criteria, if you are expecting only one item to be returned, you should use `get` instead. `get` would raise exception if less or more than 1 item is found.